# clang-format style options for enums

Tags: xcode, clang-format

Does anyone know how to configure clang-format to keep enum's on individual lines?

i.e.

```
enum {
    ONE,
    TOW,
    THREE
};
```

vs.

```
enum {ONE, TWO, THREE};
```

**EDIT:**

Here are the style options i use to match Apple's Objective-C style guide.

http://pastebin.com/0cTEhvBv

Comment: I just tried all the predefined clang-format styles and all turned single line enums (your second example) into the broken line enums (your first example).  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes, the predefined LLVM, CPP, etc styles do break them, thats correct and i want that, but i am using a config file that sets a bunch of style options to match Apple's Objective-C style guide and one of them (don't know which one), change the behavior and un-braks the lines and puts enums into a single line. I edited the OP to include my style options.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior.  I'm using your config file and I'm still getting broken line enums.

Answer (score 30):

This was intentionally introduced at some stage (so if you are unable to reproduce the behavior, you are likely on an older version).

clang-format contracts enums to a single line if all elements fit on one line. This conserves spaces and usually does not decrease readability. There is no style option, but you can override this by either adding a line comment somewhere or by adding a trailing comma after the last enumerator, e.g.:

```
enum {
    ONE,
    TOW,
    THREE,
};
```

or

```
enum {
    ONE,  // This means ...
    TOW,
    THREE
};
```

Comment: don't you know, how to achieve the same for the blocks?

Answer (score 7):

```
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: false
```

You might need a newer version of clang-format to support this.
From https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Comment: This is also useful if you're formatting protobuf, since the trailing `;` isn't optional.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use:

```
BraceWrapping:
  AfterEnum: true
```

Which will result in the following:

```
enum 
{
    ONE,
    TOW,
    THREE,
};
```

This isn't ideal because it forces a newline before the `{`, but in my opinion this is worth considering as `ColumnLimit = 0` disables all smart code wrapping, and many people may find that not worth giving up.

Answer (score 0):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39287832/1718121), setting `ColumnLimit` to `0` will also achieve this behaviour.