# clang-format removes new lines in array definition with designators

Tags: clang-format

I like to define my array values with a designator, when possible:

```
enum Mode {
    NONE,
    SPLIT_FILES,
    SINGLE_FILE,
    INVALID
};

const std::string ModeName[] = {
    [NONE] = "NONE",
    [SPLIT_FILES] = "SPLIT_FILES",
    [SINGLE_FILE] = "SINGLE_FILE",
    [INVALID] = "INVALID"
};
```

Running this through `clang-format` (3.5) mangles the new lines and makes it less readable:

```
enum RecorderMode { REC_NONE, REC_SPLIT_FILES, REC_SINGLE_FILE, REC_INVALID };

const std::string RecorderModeName[]
    = {[REC_NONE] = "NONE", [REC_SPLIT_FILES] = "SPLIT_FILES", [REC_SINGLE_FILE] = "SINGLE_FILE",
       [REC_INVALID] = "INVALID" };
```

The array definition has several problems: `= {` is moved to the next line. If I add a comma after the last array entry, the rows are indented twice.

Is there a way to keep the new lines and indentation, short of using the clang-format turn off comment?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23072223/108802) shows a work-around for the `enum` (add a comma after the last constant, or add a trailing comment after a comma), but it doesn't seem to apply to the array.

Comment: I've become a fan of [uncrustify](https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify) after finding clang-format wanting in so many ways. It's not perfect, but at least it's constantly progressing. With no input uncrustify will not change your layout; however, there are [9 minor defaults](https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify/blob/master/documentation/htdocs/configuration.txt) (line 25). To make all enums look how you want you can use `nl_enum_own_lines = force`. I'm still learning, so I'm not sure about arranging the array def how you prefer yet though. But again it will leave it alone by default.

Comment: @NoviceC: more than a year later, and I stubbled on uncrustify after rage-quitting on GNU indent and clang-format. I love it, it's so much better! I wish I tried it when you suggested it a year ago. You're maybe much better at it now, but if not let me suggest [universalindentgui](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/). It shows all options, and their effect in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34339430/108802) gave me an acceptable work-around:

Set `ColumnLimit` to 0. The trade-off is that no line is automatically wrapped, but this is worth it. All programmers at work tend to not write past column 120 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Comments on every line also works.

```
enum Mode {
  NONE,         // Comments
  SPLIT_FILES,  // On
  SINGLE_FILE,  // Every
  INVALID       // Line
};
```